# How to switch to a particular week in a FullCalendar jQuery plugin

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to switch to a particular week when a User selects any date.

On selection of the date the full calendar will display the agenda week in which the week resides.

Please suggest how to do it.

Thanks 
Prabhanjan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, but I haven't tested it yet. Let me know how it goes...

```
dayClick: function(date){
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek')
  .fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
}
```

And if your using select there is a problem when trying to use both so this should work. Again, it is untested so let me know...

```
select: function(start){
// you may have to parse the date first aka. var start = Date.parse(start);
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek')
  .fullCalendar('gotoDate', start);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2.3.1, fullCalendar does not let you chain commands. In order to achieve what you want is to call it twice.

```
dayClick: function(date){
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
}
```

or

```
dayClick: function(date){
  var $calendar=$("#calendar");
  $calendar.fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');
  $calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
}
```